# CodeIgniter: Reinitialize session after sess_destroy

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I need to log the user out and give them a message with flashdata in a certain scenario. I've tried the following code, but it seems as though the session is not being reinitialized:

```
if($user == NULL){

            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "message");
            redirect('/signin');
        }
```

How can I reinitialize the session?

Answer (score 0):

This is very hacky, but it works:

I destroy the session in one controller

```
if($user == NULL){

            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            redirect('/subscribe_error');
        }
```

Then I redirect to another function (in another controller)

```
public function null_error(){
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->session->set_flashdata("error", "message");
    redirect("/signin");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this

```
public function logout()
{
  $items = ['name', 'is_logged_in']; //Or whatever designates the person as being logged in for you
    $this->session->unset_userdata($items);
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('signin', 'refresh');
}
```